Resize partition that is mounted on root or "/"
Not too sure whether this has been done before.
I am trying to resize a partition /dev/sda3 on a single disk /dev/sda.
When I tried to use "resize2fs /dev/sda3 10G" directly, the console warned me that the drive was busy
Then I tried with df -h and found the following information on /dev/sda3
Filesystem size used available use% mounted on
/dev/sda3 600G 1.6G 598.4G 1% /
I tried again with the l option to umount the partition ie umount -l /dev/sda3. The partition unmounted without any complain. Afterwhich I tried to resize it again. It give a warning
ext2fs_check_mount_point: can't check if filesystem is mounted due to missing mtab file while determining whether /dev/sda3 is mounted

Then read about a second method which is to delete partition before resize.
fdisk /dev/sda

But it doesn't work as well, giving me an error
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: no such file or directory

All this is done after umount -l /dev/sda3 is performed.
What is the correct procedure to resize partition mounted on /?
Do we resize by resize2fs or should we do by fdisk
Thabks


Not too sure whether this has been done before.

Some filesystem types can actually be grown while mounted; Ext4 is one of them – if the server was using Ext4 or Ext3, then resize2fs would have done its job without complaining – but it sounds like you might be using the much older Ext2, in which case you'll have to unmount the filesystem somehow.
Because the root filesystem is, in general, not unmountable while the system is running (specifically it cannot be unmounted while any processes – such as init – are running from it), this means you will need to reboot to some other Linux system, e.g. any random "live CD" or "live USB".
(Actually, my suggestion is to use the opportunity to convert Ext2 to Ext4.)

One important point first:

Do we resize by resize2fs or should we do by fdisk

These resize different things. Fdisk will only resize the partition as in the container, but doesn't adjust the actual filesystem structures to match. And vice versa, resize2fs only rearranges the filesystem structures to fit the (updated) partition size.
So you will need both, in a specific order. To increase the size, you first need to expand the partition (fdisk) and then expand the filesystem (resize2fs) to fill the partition; shrinking is the opposite.
Second,

I tried again with the l option to umount the partition ie umount -l /dev/sda3. The partition unmounted without any complain

It did not. With the -l option, you told the system to pretend that the filesystem has been unmounted, but actually defer the unmount in background until "as soon as the filesystem stops being in use". But because it is the root filesystem it will never stop being in use, and therefore won't actually be unmounted.
